# The Mechanism Used to Determine Library Load Address in Perf

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, ip-address, trace, perf

How does `perf` determine the load addresses for each loaded image (e.g., shared libraries) during post-processing. For example, `perf report` uses this information to make each symbol address relative to the beginning of each loaded image. This is shown in the image below (`unwind: _int_malloc...`):
[image]

Is it stored somewhere in the `elf` binary or profiling output (i.e., `perf.data`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shared libraries load address are stored inside the perf.data file recorded during `perf record` command. You can use `perf script -D` command to dump the data from perf.data in partially decoded format. When your program is loaded by `ld-linux*.so.2` (or when required with dlopen), loader will search for library and load its segments using `mmap` syscall. These mmap events are recorded by kernel and have type PERF_RECORD_MMAP or [PERF_RECORD_MMAP2](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/perf_event.h#L891) in perf.data file. And `perf report` (and `perf script`) will reconstruct memory offsets to decode symbol names.

```
$ perf record  echo 1
$ perf script -D|grep MMAP -c
7
$ perf script -D|less
PERF_RECORD_MMAP2 ... r-xp /bin/echo
...
PERF_RECORD_MMAP2 ... r-xp /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
```

Basic ideas of `perf` are described in https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/design.txt file. To start profiling there is [`perf_event_open` syscall](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) which has `perf_event_attr *attr` argument. [Man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) describes mmap-related fields of attr:

```
   The perf_event_attr structure provides detailed configuration
   information for the event being created.

                 mmap           : 1,   /* include mmap data */
                 mmap_data      : 1,   /* non-exec mmap data */
                 mmap2          :  1,  /* include mmap with inode data */
```

Linux kernel in its `perf_events` subsystem (kernel/events) will record required events for profiled processes and export the data with fd and mmap to the profiler. `perf record` usually dumps this data from kernel into perf.data file without heavy processing (check "Woken up 1 times to write data" prints of your `perf record` output). Mmap events in kernel are recorded by [`perf_event_mmap_output`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/kernel/events/core.c#L7366) called from [`perf_event_mmap_event`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/kernel/events/core.c#L7420) which is called from [`perf_event_mmap`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/ident/perf_event_mmap). mmap syscall implementation in `mm/mmap.c` has some unconditional calls to [`perf_event_mmap`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/ident/perf_event_mmap).

perf's design.txt mentions munmap, but current implementation has no munmap field or event, event code 2 was reused to [PERF_RECORD_LOST](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/perf_event.h#L754). There were ideas that munmap can be helpful https://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg524414.html with links to https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/12/10/1 and https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/1/27/452

perf tool is part of linux kernel sources and can be viewed online with LXR/elixir website: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/tools/perf/
Processing code for mmap/mmap2 events is in perf/util/machine.c [`machine__process_mmap_event`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/tools/perf/util/machine.c#L1726) and [`machine__process_mmap2_event`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/tools/perf/util/machine.c#L1673); logged mmap arguments, returned address, offset and file name are recorded with help of `map__new` and `thread__insert_map` for the process (pid/tid) and used later to convert sample event address into symbol name.

PS: Your perf.data has size of 300+ MB, this is huge and processing can be slow. For long running programs you may want to lower perf record event sampling frequency with `-F freq` option of `perf record`: `perf record -F40` or with `-c` option.

Comment: so you say that only `mmap()` (not `munmap()`) is traced.

Comment: Yes, in perf.data file only mmaps are recorded. But event without explicit munmap tracing perf report may handle mmap/munmap/mmap sequence because second mmap will be fully recorded.

Answer (score 2):

You can't find it just by looking at the ELF executable and libraries. It can vary each run; even if ASLR was disabled by perf like GDB does, a program might use `mmap(MAP_FIXED)` before using `dlopen` of some optional library only loaded later, so dlopen would have to pick a different address than usual to map a library.  (Normal dynamic linking happens before `main` runs, not via dlopen, but presumably `perf` wants to be able to record addresses -> file mappings for any file-backed mapping.)

Probably perf saves the runtime base address of each ELF object in `perf.data`

Comment: In rare cases, a library can be **added**, **removed** and again **added** to the address space (perhaps at an address different from the old one). Therefore, `perf` should also be able to handle these situations in order to work, correctly. Am I right? I mean it should consider **timing** issues.

Comment: @TheAhmad: good question, I don't know.  If `perf` hooks mmap/munmap the way strace does, it can keep track of changes.  But maybe `perf` does something simpler and could get confused by unmapping one library and then mapping another to an overlapping address range.

Comment: perf does not hook mmap, perf_event subsystem in kernel can record mmap (and in theory munmap) events directly into buffers which are dumped to perf.data at `perf record`. Check output of `perf script -D` for  PERF_RECORD_MMAP2 and man page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html (flag mmap:1 and mmap2:1). There are no munmap event https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/perf_event.h#L891, but it was suggested in LKML in 2017 and 2018.

Comment: MUNMAP was declared in perf/design.txt https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/design.txt but not implemented in current versions; perf code 2 is used for [PERF_RECORD_LOST](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/perf_event.h#L754). Thread for adding munmap: https://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg524414.html; links to https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/12/10/1 and https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/1/27/452. Mmap records handled by  `machine__process_mmap_event` in `tools/perf/util/machine.c` of linux kernel (perf tools) with help of `map__new` `thread__insert_map`

Comment: @osgx: those comments might make a good separate answer.  Thanks for explaining the mechanism; makes sense that the kernel helps identify which address goes with which file, instead of *just* recording events with their virtual address.

Comment: @PeterCordes do you know if there is a way to get `perf` (`report`/`script`/`annotate`) to use `perf.data` to only reconstruct the binary with the true addresses from execution?

Comment: @Noah: *I* don't; I often profile static non-PIE executables for microbenchmarks.  Sounds like a good SO question to ask.

Comment: @PeterCordes fair enough, made one.